# In Perforce, can change all *.h, *.cpp files in subfolders?

Tags: perforce

I want to change all source file's type from txt into utf8.
In Perforce, can change all .h, .cpp files in subfolders?
I can't find menu at P4V.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find this option in P4V, but at the command line you can do:

```
p4 edit -t utf8 ....h
p4 edit -t utf8 ....cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out folders

Select all files

Right click -> Change Filetype -> Change base filetype and/or file attributes -> change Base Filetype as utf8.

If there are too many files, pending list doesn't show files, then

Click on "Server Data" and you'll see a setting labeled "Maximum number of files displayed per changelist*:" Raise that to 4000+ and you should see all those files.